# Proving lack of isomorphism between two rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-isomorphism

Prove that the rings $F[x,y]/(y^2-x)$ and $F[x,y]/(y^2-x^2)$ are not isomorphic for any field $F$.

I suppose I should set up an arbitrary supposed isomorphism between them and show that a contradiction arises, but I'm not really sure on the details of the implementation. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** In the latter ring you have zero divisors, as $y^2 - x^2 = (y - x)(y + x) = 0.$ Now, express the former ring in a more familiar presentation by eliminating a variable. Remember that in this quotient, $y^2 - x = 0.$

Comment: Ah yes, I see. So parametrize the former ring with a mapping, say, x onto y^2 and y onto y,  resulting in it being an integral domain, whereas we have zero divisors in the latter ring, hence it isn't a domain, and thus they're not isomorphic. Correct?

Comment: @wes That's right.